# Putting Titles on a Android ListView generated from a database

Tags: android

I am trying to put titles on a ListView that is generated from a database in android.

In the historyrow.xml

I have

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/historyTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:text="Title"/>
<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Which just displays the historyTitle text History. However, If I remove the TextView then the ListView displays correctly with a 20dip padding at the top where I would like the titles to be. Is there a way to get both displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a `LinearLayout` then add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the `LinearLayout` tag and remove the padding from the `ListView` tag.

if you are using a `RelativeLayout` then add `android:layout_below=""@id/historyTitle"` to the `ListView` tag and remove the padding from the ListView tag.

hope this helps.